# EF Core behaves differently when DbSet type parameter is changed

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 5.0.5

I have a database with two tables "t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN" and "t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT" they have the same columns. One process writes to one of the tables and another to the other but the records are structured in the exact same way, which is why they have identical columns.

My DbContext looks like this:

```
public class CiliateLoggingContext : DbContext
{
    public CiliateLoggingContext() { }

    public CiliateLoggingContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate_IN> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate_OUT> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT { get; set; }
}
```

The classes "ErrorLog_Ciliate_IN" and "ErrorLog_Ciliate_OUT" are just:

```
public partial class ErrorLog_Ciliate_IN : CiliateErrorLogBase { }

public partial class ErrorLog_Ciliate_OUT : CiliateErrorLogBase { }

public class CiliateErrorLogBase
{
    // properties representing the columns.
}
```

If I try to select logs like this:

```
Task<List<ErrorLog_Ciliate_IN>> SelectMethod()
{
    context.t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN.Where(log => log.Id > 10).OrderByDescending(log => log.Id).Take(20).ToListAsync();
}
```

Everything is fine, I get a task, I await it and it gives me a list of `ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN` objects.

Super!

However, since the classes "ErrorLog_Ciliate_IN" and "ErrorLog_Ciliate_OUT" are exactly the same I wanted to make a single "ErrorLog_Ciliate" class and use that.

```
public partial class ErrorLog_Ciliate : CiliateErrorLogBase { }
```

and change the DbContext to:

```
public class CiliateLoggingContext : DbContext
{
    public CiliateLoggingContext() { }

    public CiliateLoggingContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT { get; set; }
}
```

However EF suddenly decides to select from "ErrorLog_Ciliate", instead of "t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN".

This is what "ToQueryString()" returns with the first version of the DbContext - the one that has a separate class for each table:

Methods:

```
string SelectIN()
{
    context.t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN.Where(log => log.Id > 10).OrderByDescending(log => log.Id).Take(20).ToListAsync();
}


string SelectOUT()
{
    context.t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT.Where(log => log.Id > 10).OrderByDescending(log => log.Id).Take(20).ToListAsync();
}
```

The results:

```
DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t].[Id], [t].[Date], [t].[Type]
FROM [t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [t].[Id] DESC



DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t].[Id], [t].[Date], [t].[Type]
FROM [t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [t].[Id] DESC
```

and if I use the second version of the DbContext, where both DbSets use the same type parameter of `ErrorLog_Ciliate` the weirdest thing happens:

```
DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [a].[Id], [a].[Data], [a].[Type]
FROM [CiliateErrorLog] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [a].[Id] DESC


DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [a].[Id], [a].[Data], [a].[Type]
FROM [CiliateErrorLog] AS [a]
WHERE [a].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [a].[Id] DESC
```

Notice how now it tries to select from the name of the class, where before it tried to select from the name of the DbContext parameter.

If I use a hybrid version of the DbContext, one that has:

```
    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog_Ciliate_OUT> t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT { get; set; }
```

I get the normal first results of:

```
DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t].[Id], [t].[Date], [t].[Type]
FROM [t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_IN] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [t].[Id] DESC

DECLARE @__p_0 int = 20;

SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [t].[Id], [t].[Date], [t].[Type]
FROM [t_ErrorLogs_Ciliate_OUT] AS [t]
WHERE [t].[Id] > 10
ORDER BY [t].[Id] DESC
```

Why is this happening and how can I use the same type parameter for two properties and still have EF recognize it should select "from" the property names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF supports only one mapping in the model per entity type per `DbContext`, so you can't have two instances of the same type mapped to different tables in the same context. If you check out the [EF Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-fluent-api-to-configure-a-model) you will see that it operates on basis of types, not `DbSet`'s. So to share table structure between different tables, as you already done yourself, you need to use inheritance - most common approach is to inherit entity types from the same base class, or more esoteric one - inherit `DbContext`'s overriding entity setup in `OnModelCreating`.